# Mysql query to fetch closest image size from a set of different sizes

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm hosting product images. Each image has multiple sizes (widths) generated for it:

```
hero - 2800px
banner - 1200px
large -- 1024px
medium -- 768px
small -- 500px
preview -- 300px
thumbnail -- 200px
```

My `photos` table looks something like this:

```
id,
productId, -- what product this is a photo of
sizeId, -- foreign key to the `sizes` table
parentId, -- if this is a resized photo, the `parentId` references the original photo
filePath, -- where the photo is stored
width,
height
```

And the `sizes` table:

```
id,
name, -- e.g. 'hero', 'banner', 'large', etc.
width -- width in pixels of this size
```

When generating the image sizes, if the original image is smaller than a certain size, that size won't be generated (i.e. will never scale up an image). For example, if the original image is 1000px wide, won't generate the large, banner, or hero sizes for it.

If I'm viewing a product, I want to fetch all of that product's images. I also want to be able to specify which image size I want (e.g. if my design only needs 500px wide images, then I just need to fetch the `small` size). If I request an image size that wasn't generated for a certain photo (e.g. I'm requesting a hero image but the original image was 1000px wide and there was no hero size generated for it), I want to fetch the next largest image size instead.

I'm not sure how to efficiently fetch that next largest image from the database, if the specific size doesn't exist. I can do it algorithmically, but I'd prefer to do it all in a query.

One thing to note is that if a size doesn't exist, the next largest is always going to be the original image (because I'll scale an image down but never up, so the only cases where a size doesn't exist is when it would have required an image to be scaled up).

My idea so far is to select all the photos for a product, left join the `sizes` table on the `sizeId` matching the one I'm looking for, and have a `where` clause that only selects results that successfully joined to the `sizes` table *or* have no `parentId` (i.e. the original image). At that point, I'm not sure how to get rid of the original image items if I successfully matched one of its children to the `sizes` table (i.e. the exact size of that image I'm looking for).

```sql
SELECT p.*
FROM photos p
LEFT JOIN sizes s ON (p.sizeId = s.id)
WHERE
    p.productId=1234
    AND (p.parentId IS NULL OR (s.id IS NOT NULL AND p.sizeId = 222))
```

Like I said, the issue with this query is I'll end up with potentially two rows for each photo (i.e. if the size exists, I'll get that size and the original).

My question is, is there a better solution to this problem? If not, how would I only get one row for each photo (i.e. the size, if it exists, or the original/parent if it doesn't)?

FYI, I'm likely going to be using Mysql 8.x, but may have to use 5.x depending on a few things.

Comment: Use `ORDER BY width DESC` and `LIMIT 1` to select the largest when there are two rows.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Barmar Remember that I'm fetching all of the images for a product, so I can't limit. Your idea would work if I was getting just one image.

Answer (score 0):

This is what ended up working for me:

```sql
SELECT p.filePath as parentFilePath, p2.filePath as childFilePath
FROM photos p
LEFT JOIN photos p2 ON (p2.parentId = p.id AND p2.sizeId = <the size I want>)
WHERE
    p.productId = 1234
    AND p.parentId IS NULL -- don't get children
```

This will give me the original image (the parent) and possibly the size I want (the child). So in my program, for each row, I can check if the `childFilePath` exists and use it, or if it doesn't exist use `parentFilePath`.

If anyone thinks this is a bad solution for some reason, please comment.